# PHP code to be checked

Tags: php, while-loop

I have the following code.  What I have labelled `block 1` and `block 2` don't seem to work together but one does if i get rid of the other; when checking using `print_r.`  I am fairly new to php and was wondering if somebody could point out where I went wrong.  I had it working somewhere else before but lost the file.  Many thanks in advance.

P.S: I am aware it is a good idea to get into PDO and mysqli sooner rather than later.  But I just want to get to grips with the basics first.

```
<?php


//Connect to database

$connect = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","password");
$db = mysql_select_db("project");


//Find top 100 most popular images

$pop = mysql_query("


SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY pop DESC LIMIT 2

");

//Define local variables for images to show

//block 1//

$images = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($pop)) {
    $images[] = $row['image'];
    }

//block2//

$links = array ();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($pop)){
$links[] = $row['username'];
}

?>
```

Comment: You are not doing any error checking so it's no wonder you're not getting any meaningful error messages when things go wrong. See the manual on mysql_query for an example how to properly do it: http://php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mysql_data_seek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) will work:

```
$images = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($pop)) {
    $images[] = $row['image'];
}

mysql_data_seek( $pop, 0 );

$links = array ();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($pop)){
    $links[] = $row['username'];
}
```

However, a better / cleaner solution to your problem would be to put **both** values into their respective arrays during the first loop:

```
$links = array();
$images = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pop)) {
    $images[] = $row['image'];
    $links[] = $row['username'];
}
```

Or, even cleaner - add an array to your array:

```
$avatars = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pop)) {
    array_push(
        $avatars, 
        array('image' => $row['image'], 'username' => $row['username'])
    );
}

var_dump($avatars);
```

Answer (score 1):

> First off, [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Try with [`mysql_data_seek($pop, 0)`](http://php.net/mysql_data_seek) between the two `while` loops or replace your code with this:

```
$images = array();
$links = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($pop)) {
    $images[] = $row['image'];
    $links[] = $row['username'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  ill give it ago.  You mean to replace mysql_fetch_array with "mysql_data_seek">?

Answer (score 0):

You've already iterated over the entire result set in the first block, you need to re-seek the pointer to the begining of the the result set between the two blocks of code by doing:

```
mysql_data_seek($pop, 0);
```

Comment: I type too slow, Cthulhu, Wayne, and Jan367 beat me too it.

Comment: Wayne Whitty's solution is better than the others', as it deals with the problem, rather than give a work-around of sorts :)

Answer (score -2):

Wrong syntax.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($pop, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Comment: `MYSQL_BOTH` is assumed by default when result_type is unspecified, which is both numerically indexed and associative. See [**`mysql_fetch_array`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Call me a sucker for faster code which uses less memory over lazy programming.

Comment: No. The syntax isn't wrong. Your answer says *Wrong syntax*, which isn't true at all. Also, the issue lies elsewhere (as you can see from the other answers).

Comment: Well, the issue is incorrect syntax in my opinion, and the other answers are overly complicated. I don't understand why only one other person said to just populate both arrays in the same while loop. No need for redundant code.

Comment: That isn't the issue. Please read the first line of my answer. Populating the two in the same loop makes a difference, not just to performance, but correctness as well.